# How do I integrate postal code search?

Tags: 7, search

How to integrate number search along with string search in drupal 7?
As of now,I was able to implement string search i.e a user can search via name,place etc but I want to  implement number search so that users can search via postal code, date of birth, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Postal code](https://www.drupal.org/project/postal_code) module to integrate postal code in your site.

Please note at the moment the module only support:

USA, Canada, UK, Germany, France, Italy, Australia, Netherlands, Spain,Denmark, Sweden, Belgium, India, Poland

Comment: So is it possible to search for that particular postal code.I want to specifically search all the numbers that is added up in my site.Whether its postal code,date etc.